# Ajax запрос

Tags: ajax, php, html

Почему при Ajax запросе такой путь к файлу работает

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#send").click(function(){
        var login = $("#login").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();                
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sendMessage.php",
            data: {"login": login, "password": password},
            cache: false,                       
            success: function(response){
                var messageResp = new Array('Выполнено','Ошибка');
                var resultStat = messageResp[Number(response)];
                if(response == 0){
                    $("#login").val("");
                    $("#password").val("");
                    location.href='google.ru';
                }
                $("#resp").text(resultStat).show().delay(1500).fadeOut(800);

            }
        });
        return false;

    });
});
</script>
```

А такой нет

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#send").click(function(){
        var login = $("#login").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();                
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://удаленный сервер/sendMessage.php",
            data: {"login": login, "password": password},
            cache: false,                       
            success: function(response){
                var messageResp = new Array('Выполнено','Ошибка');
                var resultStat = messageResp[Number(response)];
                if(response == 0){
                    $("#login").val("");
                    $("#password").val("");
                    location.href='google.ru';
                }
                $("#resp").text(resultStat).show().delay(1500).fadeOut(800);

            }
        });
        return false;

    });
});
</script>
```

Файл index.html содержит форму

```
<form  method="post" >
        <p>Логин:<br><input name="login" type="text" id="login"></p>
        <p>Пароль:<br><input name="password" rows="5" cols="50" id="password"></p>
        <input name="js" type="hidden" value="no" id="js">
        <p><input name="button" type="submit" value="Отправить" id="send"></p>
        <p><span id="resp"></span></p>
</form>
```

Файл sendMessage.php содержит запрос

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","demo","demo");
mysql_select_db("demo",$db);
mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251");
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251");

if(empty($_POST['js'])){
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_REQUEST['login']."'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($q);
if(($_REQUEST['login']==$result['username']) && (md5(md5($_REQUEST['password']))==$result['password']))
{
    echo 0; //Выполнено
}
else{
    echo 1; //Ошибка
}
}
?>
```

Почему первый Ajax запрос работает, а второй запрос, с путем к файлу (sendMessage.php) на удаленном сервере не работает в чем может быть проблема, и как ее исправить ???

Comment: видимо у вас файл, в котором у скрипта прописан относительный путь, лежит не в корневой директории, где и находится sendMessage.php

Comment: Да он лежит не в корневой директории, но мне так и надо. Надо чтобы mobile приложение взаимодействовало с БД

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Короче в моем случае проблему решила вот это строка

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

ее я вставил в файл к которому я обращался sendMessage.php

```
// можно ограничить домен, для которого доступен ответ
// header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://javascript.ru');
```